# Why does this argument show why the set of all finite subsets of a countably infinite set is countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am at a loss to understand the justification behind the following statement being false and would appreciate someone explaining what this particular argument is saying:

> The set of all finite subsets of a countably infinite set is uncountable.
> **Answer**: False. Any countable set has a bijection with the naturals, and one can list the subsets in order of the sum of their values. Every finite subset has a finite sum and therefore will appear in the listing.

I am not sure how this argument proves the falsehood of this statement, or what the process of its logic is. Do we not have to say something about how different subsets will have the same sums? I would appreciate a more formal version of the above argument so I could understand what point it is making.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This argument is incomplete but it does work if the details are filled in. The idea is this: if we let $P_f(\mathbb{N})$ denote the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, then there is a function

$$\text{sum} : P_f(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{N}$$

which sends a finite subset $\{ n_1, \dots n_k \}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ to the sum $\sum n_i$ of all of its elements. This function has finite fibers; that is, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there are only finitely many subsets summing to $n$. This means we can write down an explicit list of all such subsets by going in order based on sum, and then just listing the subsets with a given sum in any order (below I use [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)). An example of such a list:

- $\emptyset$ (the unique subset with sum $0$)
- $\{ 1 \}$ (the unique subset with sum $1$)
- $\{ 2 \}$ (the unique subset with sum $2$)
- $\{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 3 \}$
- $\{ 1, 3 \}, \{ 4 \}$
- $\{ 1, 4 \}, \{ 2, 3 \}, \{ 5 \}$

and so forth. And an infinite list is the same thing as a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, where the bijection sends a number $n$ to the $n^{th}$ item on the list. The same argument also shows that the set of all finite *sequences* of natural numbers is countable.

More precisely the claim is the following:

> **Claim:** If $X$ is a set and $f : X \to \mathbb{N}$ is a function such that each fiber $f^{-1}(n), n \in \mathbb{N}$ is finite, then $X$ is countable.

$\mathbb{N}$ can be replaced here with any countable set, and "finite" can be replaced with "countable" but the proof is harder; that's a variation of "a countable union of countable sets is countable." Here we have "a countable union of finite sets is countable."

---

An alternative argument that is quite cute is to explicitly write down a bijection from $P_f(\mathbb{N})$ to $\mathbb{N}$. This can be done by interpreting a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ as a number in base $2$; that is, we send a subset $\{ n_1, \dots n_k \}$ to the number $2^{n_1} + \dots + 2^{n_k}$. The statement that this is a bijection is exactly the statement that the base-$2$ expansion of a number exists and is unique!

---

Here is another alternative and much more general argument you can use on many other sets. Generally speaking I think the intuition I would encourage people to develop about countability is that a set is (at most) countable precisely when it is possible to specify an element of that set with a "finite amount of information." This can be made precise as the claim that the set of (finite) words using a finite alphabet is always countable, and you can use this to derive all of the other familiar countability results.

From this perspective a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ can be specified with a finite amount of information because you can write it down as a finite word using the alphabet $, \{ \} 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9$. This is somewhat "inefficient" but the point is that you can see this is true at a glance without doing any additional work.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is the following:

Let $X$ be a countable set, let $\varphi:X\to\mathbb{N}$ be a bijection, and let $\mathscr{F}(X)$ be the collection of all finite subsets of $X$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let

$$F_n=\left\{Y\in\mathscr{F}(X):\sum_{x\in Y}\varphi(x)=n\right\}.$$

Then each $F_n$ is finite, the $F_n$'s are disjoint, and

$$\mathscr{F}(X)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_n.$$

Thus being a countable union of disjoint finite sets, $\mathscr{F}(X)$ is countable.